# How to hidden field in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, hidden-field, contact-form-7

sorry my english bad,i have a problem : i have a form, one field i store data and i want to hidden it, i used to tag hidden in contact form 7 but it is not working

> my setting contact form 7  : 
>   [Image setting form](https://prnt.sc/fvhvfm)
>
> Form after i set
>   [image form after set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tthj7.jpg)

Answer (score 12):

You should use the below formatt

[hidden your-email default:user_email "example@example.com"]

for more detail follow the https://contactform7.com/hidden-field/

Answer (score 6):

input:

```
[hidden form-name default:"popup contact form" ]
```

output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="popup contact form" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden">
```

Answer (score 1):

you may can use hidden field like this.
Ex . [hidden name default:name "Abc User"]

Answer (score 0):

How to add hidden field (page title, current page) in contact form 7

go to past code contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php

```
private function form_hidden_fields() {
    $hidden_fields = array(
        '_wpcf7' => $this->id(),
        '_wpcf7_version' => WPCF7_VERSION,
        '_wpcf7_locale' => $this->locale(),
        '_wpcf7_unit_tag' => $this->unit_tag(),
        '_wpcf7_container_post' => 0,
        '_wpcf7_posted_data_hash' => '',
        'page-title' => get_the_title(),
        'page-url' => get_the_permalink(),
    );
```

front end page show

Answer (score -2):

You can just add a class hidden as style.

```
[text class:hidden "Field Name"]
```

Then add this to your style sheet.

```
.hidden {
    display: none!important;
}
```